Prove that $1<\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+y}}+\sqrt{\frac{xy}{xy+8}}<2$ for $x,y>0$
Prove that $1<\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+y}}+\sqrt{\frac{xy}{xy+8}}<2$ for $x,y>0$.
Here are two ways that I have tried (which all failed)

Rewrite the summand more symmetrically as $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+y}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{8}{xy}}}$ and we consider the function $f(t):=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t}}$. Then $f$ is convex and hence I tried to appeal to Jensen's inequality but I ended up with this mess: $f(\frac{1}{3}(x+y+\frac{8}{xy}))$ which doesn't seem to simplify.

Then I tried to use the machinery from multivariable calculus and find the max and min using partial differentiation. But again the derivative looks horrible and I was not able to solve for it.


Any help would be appreciated.

A duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1646819/42969 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2255136/42969 ?

This question is similar to: Prove that $1 < \frac{1}{\sqrt {1+x}} +\frac{1}{\sqrt {1+a}} + \sqrt{\frac{ax}{ax+8}} < 2$ for $a, x < 0$. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
